# ImportError No module named 'plotlytools' when importing Cufflinks

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, visualization, plotly

My system environment: `Windows 8.1, WinPython 3.4.3.1, pandas 0.16, plotly 1.6.14, cufflinks 0.2`

I have no idea what's causing the issue. I'm attempting to use the tutorial outlined here [cufflinks nbviewer tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/santosjorge/cfaaf43b40db19d6127a)

However when I try to import the cufflinks module I get the following output.

[image]

That doesn't make sense to me because as far as I can tell the files are all set up correctly within the folder and I don't see any obvious errors within the files themselves. See below image:

[image]

I also looked at the `__init__.py` file and didn't see anything unusual.

[image]

And lastly I looked at the actual `plotlytools.py` file to see if anything looked odd and nothing jumped out at me.

[image]

Any help figuring this one out would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE: If this helps here is a print out of my `sys.path`

[image]

Comment: Try opening a console and `import cufflinks.plotlytools`

Comment: Why is `lib` capitalized in the path you manually checked?

Comment: import cufflinks.plotlytools produces the same error. @cel I'm not sure why `Lib` is capitalized. Could be a `WinPython` thing but it hasn't affected the use of any other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to import the module after implementing the following workarounds:

1. In the `utils.py` file I added `()` to all the `print` statements, example: `print 'string'` became `print('string')`.
2. I copied then deleted the `utils.py` and `colors.py` files and pasted the contents into the `plotlytools.py` file.
3. I updated all the import references in the remaining files.
4. to use the pandastools functionality, specifically the `df.iplot` method, it was also necessary to update the encoding and decoding methods for the `colors.py` file from `str.encode('hex') and str.decode('hex')` to `import codecs; codecs.encode(str,'hex'); codecs.decode(str,'hex')`
5. I also updated the generator methods from `gen_object.next()` to `next(gen_object)`

At this point all the functionality of the module seems to be restored.